# readonly_fields returns empty value in django inlined models

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views, django-urls

i am new in django framework, in my current try, i have two models (Client and Facture). Facture is displayed as a TabularInline in client change view.

i want display a link for each inlined facture object to download the file. so i added a custom view that download the facture file, but dont know how to link to it

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

class Facture(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numero = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=rand_code)
    ...
```

and in the admin.py:

```
class FactureInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Facture
    extra = 0

    readonly_fields = ('numero', 'dl_link')

    def DLFacture(self, request, obj):
        ...
        response.write(pdf)
        return response

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(FactureAdmin, self).get_urls()
        from django.conf.urls import url
        download_url = [
            url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/download/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.DLFacture), name="download"),
        ]
        return download_url + urls

    def dl_link(self, obj):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse("admin:clients_facture_download", args=[obj.pk])

admin.site.register(Facture, FactureAdmin)

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        FactureInline,
    ]
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

i get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'clients_facture_download' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

all works fine when i change the reverse url to

```
reverse("admin:clients_facture_change", args=[obj.pk])
```

so any one could help me know how to reverse the download view and if i am doing thinks right ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are using `name='download'`, but trying to reverse `clients_facture_download`.

I would try changing the url from

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/download/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.DLFacture), name="download"),
```

to

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/download/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.DLFacture), name="clients_fracture_download"),
```

Secondly, InlineModelAdmin [does not have](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options) a `get_urls` method. You should move it to your `ClientAdmin` class.

Comment: it didnt work too ! the url i used works fine when i use it in list_display for Facture(admin.ModelAdmin). i think the problem is related with the use of TabularInline class

Comment: As you say, the inline class does not have a `get_urls` method. You should move it to your model admin class.

Comment: if i do so, how would i get the facture object pk ? could you write some code please

Comment: Having the `DLFacture` as a class method probably complicates things. I would write a separate method `def download_facture(request, pk):` (remember to update the url pattern). The primary key is included in the url as `pk`, so you can do `facture = Facture.objects.get(pk=pk)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to reverse the order in the url:

```
url(r'^download/(?P<pk>\d+)$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.DLFacture), name="download"),
    ]
```

Comment: it didn't work too! i thnik the link should be r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/download/$. object change url is in that order client/1/change/